# Why do I get a non-vector type when using sinkVector & runConduit?

Tags: haskell, conduit

I have a conduit with this type signature:

```
processFileName :: (MonadResource m, MonadThrow m, PrimMonad m) =>
  ConduitT FilePath (MapRow Text) m ()
```

The following conduit constructor that uses it type checks:

```
readFnameData2 ::MonadResource m => ConduitT (MapRow Text) FilePath m ()
  -> ConduitT (MapRow Text) Void m (Vector (MapRow Text))
readFnameData2 files = files
    .| processFileName
    .| sinkVector
```

However, when I try to modify this to actually return a `Vector` in the `IO` monad, I get an unexpected result:

```
readFnameData ::MonadResource m => ConduitT (MapRow Text) FilePath m () -> IO (Vector (MapRow Text))
readFnameData files = do
  fNameRows <- files
   .| processFileName
   .| sinkVector
  fNameRows & runConduit
```

yields the error:

```
    * Couldn't match type `Map Text Text' with `Vector (MapRow Text)'
      Expected type: IO (Vector (MapRow Text))
        Actual type: IO (MapRow Text)
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: fNameRows & runConduit
      In the expression:
        do fNameRows <- files .| processFileName .| sinkVector
           fNameRows & runConduit
      In an equation for `readFnameData':
          readFnameData files
            = do fNameRows <- files .| processFileName .| sinkVector
                 fNameRows & runConduit
   |
70 |       fNameRows & runConduit
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I feel I must be missing something basic here, but not sure what to look at to uncover the mystery.

**Update:** To elaborate on my first comment below, we can see the intermediate `ConduitT` error:

```
    readFnameData3 ::MonadResource m => ConduitT (MapRow Text) FilePath m ()
      -> IO (Vector (MapRow Text))
    readFnameData3 files = runConduit (readFnameData2 files)

    * Couldn't match type `Map Text Text' with `()'
      Expected type: ConduitT () Void m (Vector (MapRow Text))
        Actual type: ConduitT (MapRow Text) Void m (Vector (MapRow Text))
    * In the first argument of `runConduit', namely
        `(readFnameData2 files)'
      In the expression: runConduit (readFnameData2 files)
      In an equation for `readFnameData3':
          readFnameData3 files = runConduit (readFnameData2 files)
   |
67 |     readFnameData3 files = runConduit (readFnameData2 files)      
   |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This shows a mismatch in type for the first field of `ConduitT`. Not sure why `sinkVector` is not returning a unit type for this, since all the  `runConduit*` seem to have unit in this position, and as it is a sink, it can't accept further meaningful inputs, so I guess it would sort of make sense for this to be `()` - though not sure why `Void` isn't a better option.

Comment: Tthe issue maybe be related to the fact that runConduit requires unit (`()`) for the input field of `ConduitT`, and for some reason, `sinkVector` is returning a non-unit field here (not sure why). In particular it is `MapRow Text` instead of `()`.

Answer (score 0):

I can corrected the intermediate functions to be

```
readFnameData2 ::MonadResource m => ConduitT () FilePath m ()
  -> ConduitT () Void m (Vector (MapRow Text))
readFnameData2 files = files
    .| processFileName
    .| sinkVector

readFnameData3 ::MonadResource m => ConduitT () FilePath m ()
  -> m (Vector (MapRow Text))
readFnameData3 files = runConduit (readFnameData2 files)
```

The issue here was that `files` should have had the unit input type, being a source!

```
readFnameData ::MonadResource m => ConduitT () FilePath m () -> m (Vector (MapRow Text))
readFnameData files = runConduit $ files .| processFileName .| sinkVector
```